How do you estimate overall population means from stratified random sampling when data is missing?
A telephone survey is conducted of 200 houses from 20 counties within a Country. Each of the 20 counties serve as a stratum. A SRS of telephone numbers from county telephone directories was selected in each county. When a household could not be contacted or was unwilling to participate in the study, an alternate telephone number was used, until the desired sample size in the stratum was reached. The survey is investigating the number of people living in each household.
I am required to find the average number of people living in the house. Along with a 90% CI.
The data set i have been given provides the county name, population of each county and the sample size for each county and the number of people living in the household for each house contacted.
I know how to do this, I need to find
$$\bar{y}_{str}=\Sigma^{20}_{h=1} \frac{N_h}{N}\bar{y}_h$$
where h denotes each county, $N_h$ denotes the population for each county h, N denotes the total population of the country and $\bar{y}_h$ denotes the sample mean.
However two of the counties are not in the data set i have been given so i do not know the population size of these counties and therefore do not have an accurate N value. And even if nobody was surveyed in these counties (atleast that's what i'm assuming as the reason for not being in the data set), the population of these samples would have an affect on the overall population average, would they not?
Also in order to calculate the CI, i need to know the standard deviation for the sample in each stratum. However along with the two counties that simply do not appear in the data set, there is another county in which only one house was surveyed and as such i cannot work out the standard deviation of this sample because there was only one observation.
But then i do not understand how i am meant to calculate the CI if one the samples only has one observation, because its not as though the standard deviation for this sample is 0, it is undefined.

This might be a slightly better fit for the stats SE, but I'll give a bit of an answer here.

There's a bit going on here, but here are a few observations and things that you could consider.
First, there are many methods for treating missing data, depending on the assumed mechanism by which it is missing. Probably the seminal work on this topic is Nonresponse in Household Interview Surveys by Groves and Couper. Broadly speaking, if you can generate a model that explains the relation between the missingness and the responses based on information you already have, you can use that to "fill in the gaps" somehow.
With that said, this sentence is concerning:

When a household could not be contacted or was unwilling to participate in the study, an alternate telephone number was used, until the desired sample size in the stratum was reached.

The reason this is a problem is because it greatly affects the assumption of "simple random sampling". Groves would consider this "Not Missing At Random" (NMAR), aka "Nonignorable nonresponse", and the problem is that there is potentially a correlation between the variable of interest and whether the household is included in the survey, in a way that you can't accurately measure (e.g. maybe smaller households are harder to contact because it's more likely that everyone is out of the house, or maybe bigger households are too busy to participate).
If, however, you choose to ignore that, then there are some things you can do, including:

Post-stratifying the sample to combine counties with a low response rate together with other, similar counties with better response.

Imputing missing data to fill in the blanks.


Both of these methods require some additional work to estimate the impact on variance, either theoretically (by modelling the variance introduced) or empirically (via replicate techniques and/or multiple imputation).

Thank you for your reply. I didn't realise that there was a stats SE so will try posting there.
Also this is part of university coursework, all the information in the question, is all the information i have been given to write a report. So i'm not sure if i'm expected to do something about the missing data or just comment on it. I can find the populations of the missing counties, so what you suggested may work. However I'm not sure what to do about the county in which the sample only contains one house.
